# Android-Listview

Tags: android, android-listview, android-arrayadapter

I'm retrieving data (user information), and dispaying it from a `HashMap` to `ArrayAdpater` (in listview). Whenever I click (or even scroll) on listview my application crashes.

Any idea why it's happening? Here's what I'm doing:

```
//..
  Handler handler = new Handler();
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_app_activity3);
    information=new String[50];
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    Custom custom = (Custom) intent.getSerializableExtra("custom");
    HashMap<String, String> list = custom.getList();
    //Set s = list.entrySet();
    Iterator items=list.values().iterator();
    int i=0;
    while (items.hasNext())
    {
        information[i]=(String) items.next();
        System.out.println(information[i]);
        i++;
    }
    lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listview1);
    lv.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,information));
    lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true); 
}
```

---

Here is my Logcat:

01-22 22:45:20.286: D/AndroidRuntime(332): Shutting down VM
01-22 22:45:20.286: W/dalvikvm(332): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
01-22 22:45:20.306: E/AndroidRuntime(332): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-22 22:45:20.306: E/AndroidRuntime(332): java.lang.NullPointerException
01-22 22:45:20.306: E/AndroidRuntime(332):  at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:355)
01-22 22:45:20.306: E/AndroidRuntime(332):  at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getView(ArrayAdapter.java:323)
01-22 22:45:20.306: E/AndroidRuntime(332):  at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:1294)
01-22 22:45:20.306: E/AndroidRuntime(332):  at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1198)
01-22 22:45:20.306: E/AndroidRuntime(332):  at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1109)
01-22 22:45:20.306: E/AndroidRuntime(332):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8171)
01-22 22:45:20.306: E/AndroidRuntime(332):  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3132)
01-22 22:45:20.306: E/AndroidRuntime(332):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1012)
01-22 22:45:20.306: E/AndroidRuntime(332):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:381)
01-22 22:45:20.306: E/AndroidRuntime(332):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:304)
01-22 22:45:20.306: E/AndroidRuntime(332):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8171)
01-22 22:45:20.306: E/AndroidRuntime(332):  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3132)
01-22 22:45:20.306: E/AndroidRuntime(332):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:245)
01-22 22:45:20.306: E/AndroidRuntime(332):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8171)
01-22 22:45:20.306: E/AndroidRuntime(332):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:526)
01-22 22:45:20.306: E/AndroidRuntime(332):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:304)
01-22 22:45:20.306: E/AndroidRuntime(332):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8171)
01-22 22:45:20.306: E/AndroidRuntime(332):  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3132)
01-22 22:45:20.306: E/AndroidRuntime(332):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:245)
01-22 22:45:20.306: E/AndroidRuntime(332):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8171)
01-22 22:45:20.306: E/AndroidRuntime(332):  at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:801)
01-22 22:45:20.306: E/AndroidRuntime(332):  at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1727)
01-22 22:45:20.306: E/AndroidRuntime(332):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-22 22:45:20.306: E/AndroidRuntime(332):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
01-22 22:45:20.306: E/AndroidRuntime(332):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
01-22 22:45:20.306: E/AndroidRuntime(332):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-22 22:45:20.306: E/AndroidRuntime(332):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
01-22 22:45:20.306: E/AndroidRuntime(332):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
01-22 22:45:20.306: E/AndroidRuntime(332):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
01-22 22:45:20.306: E/AndroidRuntime(332):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-22 22:45:22.496: I/Process(332): Sending signal. PID: 332 SIG: 9

Comment: post your logcat error report..

Comment: Post the onclick event code of listview..

Comment: Check this code for listview example : http://www.ezzylearning.com/tutorial.aspx?tid=1659127

Answer (score 0):

```
ListView lv = (listView) findViewById(R.Id.listView1);
```

Further define your ListView.